# Get complete Joining Object using Criteria Builder

Tags: java, hibernate, join, hibernate-criteria

```
    select s.student_name, teach from STUDENTS_TEACHER as sl 
    inner join STUDENT as s on sl.id = s.stud_id 
    inner join TEACHER as teach on sl.id = teach.teach_id
```

I am trying to get StudentName and Teacher.class entity in the above query.

Here STUDENTS_TEACHER is mapping each Student_id with Teacher_Id

How can I get the same using CriteraBuilder

```
    Root<StudentTeacherMapping> studentTeacherMapping =criteriaQuery.from(StudentTeacherMapping.class);
    Join<StudentTeacherMapping, Student> studentJoin = attributeCategoryMappingRoot.join("student");
    Join<StudentTeacherMapping, Teacher> teachJoin = attributeCategoryMappingRoot.join("teacher");
    criteriaQuery.multiselect(studentJoin.get("StudentName"), Teacher.get("TeacherSub"), ? );
```

How can I get the Teacher Object for here?

Comment: Why are you mixing projection of simple types with an Entity type?

Comment: I am trying to get a Map<String(Student name), Teacher>